# I've been waiting for her for some time now

Tags: phrase-usage

I was waiting for someone and a friend called me and asked where I was. I said:

"I've been waiting for someone in a restaurant **for some time now.**"

Does it mean 'a fairly long time' depending on the context? I mean in my context people consider half an hour to one hour a very long time to wait in a restaurant, but it's totally different for an airport.

Or can it be used even when talking about a short period of time?

Answer (score 2):

'Some time' means 'a long time considering the circumstances'. It might be used about a half-hour wait in a restaurant (if a time has been agreed), or, as you suggest, longer in an airport, especially if you feel you have been waiting too long. I can correctly say 'I have been using a wireless keyboard for some time' if I have been using it for two years, or "It has been known for some time that penicillin kills bacteria' if that fact has been known for 93 years.